# How to read the python documentation offline in emacs?

Tags: python

Sometimes I use `ctrl h i` or `M-x woman`, though I almost always head to the web for basic queries like *python find line in string*. Do I need to download this[0], that[1] or something else before leaving to a remote island and come back as python wizard after years of being offline and `M-x doctor`?

[0] https://docs.python.org/3/download.html
[1] https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/python-docs/

Comment: See [info-python](https://github.com/emacs-pe/info-python.el) which had enough information for me to build my own info files for python 3. There are premade info files if you are looking for python 2.